# I have been trying to use PnP PowerShell to get all the users of the web and end up having memory exception

Tags: powershell, exception, sharepoint

The below PowerShell script was written inside a for each loop of all sub webs of a site collection:

```
$users = Get-PnPUser -WithRightsAssigned -Web $currentSubweb
```

This is to retrieve all the users within the site.
The above line throws memory exception:

> Exception of type system.OutOfMemoryException

I have used `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to increase the memory.

```
Start-Service WinRM

Get-Item -Path WSMan:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 8192
Restart-Service winrm
```

This has not solved the problem.

During the beginning of execution, the code does not throw any error. but after processing for 9 + sub-webs the exception occurs.

Any pointers will be of great help.

```
#Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2019 -AllowClobber

try
{


#Clear-Variable -Name "IsUserAvailableIngroup"


$FileName = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")            
$Logfile = New-Item -itemType File -Path E:\UserConsentPermission\UserConsentPermissionLog -Name ("LogFile" + $FileName + ".log") 


$Connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url "URL of the site to update" -UseWebLogin -ReturnConnection
$ListName = "External_Users_Permission"
$List = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName


Connect-PnPOnline -Url "URL of the site to retriev User Info" -UseWebLogin
$members = Get-PnPGroupMembers -Identity 'ExternalUsers'

#New-Variable -Name "IsUserAvailableIngroup" -Value 0
Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value (Get-Date) -PassThru
 
$currentSubwebs = Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse

foreach ($currentSubweb in $currentSubWebs)
{
   Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value $currentSubweb.Url -PassThru
   
   
   $users = Get-PnPUser -WithRightsAssigned -Web $currentSubweb
   foreach ($user in $users)
   {

    Set-Variable -Name "IsUserAvailableIngroup" -Value 0
    if(!($user.Email.Contains("esa.int")))
     {
     
     foreach($member in $members)
     {
     
      if($user.LoginName.Equals($member.LoginName)) 
      {
       
      Set-Variable -Name "IsUserAvailableIngroup" -Value 1
      Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value  $user.Email "/" $user.LoginName "is already available in ExternalUser Group" -PassThru
      } 
      }
     if($IsUserAvailableIngroup.Equals(0))#change to "O" while executing
     {
      Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value ($user.LoginName.ToString()) -PassThru
      
      Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value "is not available in ExternalUser Group" -PassThru
      Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName $user.LoginName -Identity 'ExternalUsers' 
      Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value "is added to group ExternalUser" -PassThru
      
      $SiteName = $currentSubweb.Title
      $SiteURL = $currentSubweb.Url
      $userEmailAd = $user.Email
    
      $items = Get-PnPListItem -Connection $Connection -List $List -Query "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Email_x0020_Address'/><Value Type='Text'>$userEmailAd</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Site_x0020_URL'/><Value Type='Text'>$SiteURL</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>"

      if($items.Count.Equals(0)){

      Add-PnPListItem -Connection $Connection -List $List -Values @{"Title" = $SiteName; "Site_x0020_URL"= $SiteURL; "Email_x0020_Address"= $userEmailAd}
      Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value ($user.LoginName.ToString()) -PassThru
      Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value "is added to ExternalUserpermission list" -PassThru
    
      }
      else
      {
       Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value ($user.LoginName.ToString()) -PassThru
       Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value  "is already present in the ExternalUserpermission list" -PassThru
      write-Host $user.LoginName  "is already present in the Externaluserpermission List"
     }
  }
   }
}
}

Catch
{

Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value "Error Occurred" -PassThru
Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value $_.Tostring() -PassThru
Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value $_.Exception.Message -PassThru
Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value "Failing at line:" -PassThru
Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber -PassThru
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the structure of your code (likely your loops), not with the command you're running. You'll need to post more info for us to be able to help.

Comment: I have added the code here